# how to use array in sed shell command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sed

I am trying to do a list of name:

```
list = a, b, c, d, e
sed "/$list/d" output_file.txt
```

so that lines containing those variables a,b,c,d,e would be excluded from the output_file

Anyone please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
list=(a b c d e)
(IFS="|"; grep -vE "(${list[*]})" file)
```

or with GNU sed:

```
list=(a b c d e)
(IFS="|"; sed -E "/(${list[*]})/d" file)
```

Comment: It looks like the output shown on the terminal when I run the script is correct but then when I open the file that I generated with my code alone with this one it still does not exclude the list

Comment: Try this: `list=(a b c d e); (IFS="|"; grep -vE "(${list[*]})" input_file > output_file)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a BASH array to generate a regex with pipe (alternation):

```
list=(a b c d e) # original array

printf -v re "%s|" "${list[@]}" # genera a regex delimited by |

sed -E "/${re%|}/d" file # use sed on this regex
```

Comment: To save changes inline for `sed` use: `sed -E -i.bak "/${re%|}/d" file`